# WinRT application login by pressing Enter key with MVVM light

Tags: c#, windows-8, mvvm-light, winrt-xaml

I'm developing an application in which the user needs to enter a username and password to login.

I'm using the MVVM light framework to separate my view from my viewmodels.
For now I have a button on my view which tapped event is caught on the corresponding viewmodel.

I would also would like to have the possibility if the user presses the enter button they can also login. In WPF you had the ability to set a button as IsDefault, but it seems not possible in WinRT.

How can I do this?

Comment: Whops. Wong button... Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can put this code into your viewmodel and check if the enter key is pressed, then when it is pressed just launch the same method you would launch if your button was pressed

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += (sender, arg) =>
        {
            if (arg.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
            {
                //Your login method
            }

        };
```

Comment: this will break the MVVM pattern of not having UI related code in the viewmodel.  I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment I don't recommend using UI code in the view model.  Use a trigger to bind to a command for a keypress in the textbox.

```
<TextBox>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommandCommand="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

be sure to incluide the following in your xaml declarations:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but those triggers are not available in my WinRT application.

Answer (score 0):

There's a virtual method on the Page called OnKeyDown() you can override.  This is safer than subscribing to events and fits MVVM better.  I prefer to cast DataContext to my view model type and call whatever I want.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve this with behaviors:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="KeyDown">
    <core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="Load" />
  </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

You'll have to reference:

```
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

However, it only works for all keys. I didn't see any possibility to filter for a certain key.

Comment: Could you please suggest some example?

Comment: What example would you like? I already included some XAML. The only thing you need is an event handler method in your ViewModel.

Answer (score -1):

There are:

```
xmlns:i="using:WinRtBehaviors"
xmlns:b="using:Win8nl.Behaviors"

<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <b:EventToCommandBehavior Event="Loaded" Command="LoadedCommand"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

from Nuget.